# Can't run applets in browser

Tags: java, html, security, applet

Right now in my Java online class, I am on a GUI unit and I need to run applets from HTML files. After making an HTML file with an applet, when I opened it in my browser (Chrome) it wouldn't run because of the security settings. What should I do?

Comment: Can you explain better please?

Comment: What error messages do you get?  What does the code look like?  What version of the JRE are you using?

Comment: This picture may help: http://i.imgur.com/uXBt1oZ.png

Comment: Ah yes, I've had that before, well go to your settings and go onto exceptions and add that web address to the exceptions list, I cannot give exact instructions as I'm on a mac, but the principle is the same, normally if you click on the "error" it should give you some options, and may link you to your security settings which you can then add exception

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

Preferably you need to go to the java control panel which you might do by clicking on start button on windows 7 and go to control panel, in the search bar of control panel search for java control panel. Once you enter there, click on security tab where, you would find an exception bar to enter a website URL. Please enter the URL which you use to open the HTML file and add it. Try running it once again.

If you are still not able to run it, consider checking you init() method at times if there is any issue in it, it does not lets you run the applet.

This alternative is to completely remove Java from you system and again install it from start. Also, you may try to upgrade your java plug-in for the browser. It should run then.

Regards,
Saurabh Bhatia